# Check multiple arrays for specific value and calculate average of another value - swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have some pretty confusing code - at least I think so! And I wanted to ask you guys, if there was a simpler way to do this, so that this part of the code wouldn't take up that much space.

Here's what my code is able to:
Make a string into an array with `components(separatedBy: "")`. It need to do that because the `allCars` is actually a value that it is getting online.

Check the last value to get the category of the vehicle. Check how many `car` categories, `motorcycle` categories etc. there are.

Check the weight of the vehicle (by looking at the array of the specific vehicle in `countingVehicleOne`, `countingVehicleTwo` ... etc.

Calculate the average of each of the vehicles.

I should say that sometimes there is not going to be a car.. Sometimes there are not going to be a motorcycle - that is very important.

Here is the code:

```
let allCars = "Peugeot#950#yellow#car--Yamaha#180#black#motorcycle--Kawazasaki#210#green#motorcycle"



let countingCategories = allCars.components(separatedBy: "--")

var carWeight: Int = 0
var motorcycleWeight: Int = 0
var carCount: Int = 0
var motorcycleCount: Int = 0



if countingCategories.count == 1 {

    let countingVehicleOne = countingCategories[0].components(separatedBy: "#")





    if countingVehicleOne[3] == "car" {
        carWeight = Int(countingVehicleOne[1])!
        var carCount: Int = 1

    } else if countingVehicleOne[3] == "motorcycle" {
        motorcycleWeight = Int(countingVehicleOne[1])!
        var motorcycleCount: Int = 1

    }

} else if countingCategories.count == 2 {

    let countingVehicleOne = countingCategories[0].components(separatedBy: "#")
    let countingVehicleTwo = countingCategories[1].components(separatedBy: "#")



    let numbers:[[String]] = [countingVehicleOne, countingVehicleTwo]


    for number in numbers {
        if number.last == "car"{
            carCount = carCount + 1
        }
    }


    for number in numbers {
        if number.last == "motorcycle"{
            motorcycleCount = motorcycleCount + 1
        }
    }



    if countingVehicleOne[3] == "car" {
        carWeight = Int(countingVehicleOne[1])!

    } else if countingVehicleOne[3] == "motorcycle" {
        motorcycleWeight = Int(countingVehicleOne[1])!

    }



    if countingVehicleTwo[3] == "car" {
        carWeight = Int(countingVehicleTwo[1])! + carWeight

    } else if countingVehicleTwo[3] == "motorcycle" {
        motorcycleWeight = Int(countingVehicleTwo[1])! + motorcycleWeight

    }




} else if countingCategories.count == 3 {

    let countingVehicleOne = countingCategories[0].components(separatedBy: "#")
    let countingVehicleTwo = countingCategories[1].components(separatedBy: "#")
    let countingVehicleThree = countingCategories[2].components(separatedBy: "#")



    let numbers:[[String]] = [countingVehicleOne, countingVehicleTwo, countingVehicleThree]


    for number in numbers {
        if number.last == "car"{
            carCount = carCount + 1
        }
    }


    for number in numbers {
        if number.last == "motorcycle"{
            motorcycleCount = motorcycleCount + 1
        }
    }



    if countingVehicleOne[3] == "car" {
        carWeight = Int(countingVehicleOne[1])!

    } else if countingVehicleOne[3] == "motorcycle" {
        motorcycleWeight = Int(countingVehicleOne[1])!

    }



    if countingVehicleTwo[3] == "car" {
        carWeight = Int(countingVehicleTwo[1])! + carWeight

    } else if countingVehicleTwo[3] == "motorcycle" {
        motorcycleWeight = Int(countingVehicleTwo[1])! + motorcycleWeight

    }

    if countingVehicleTwo[3] == "car" {
        carWeight = Int(countingVehicleThree[1])! + carWeight

    } else if countingVehicleTwo[3] == "motorcycle" {
        motorcycleWeight = Int(countingVehicleThree[1])! + motorcycleWeight

    }




}

let averageCarWeight = carWeight / carCount
let averageMotorcycleWeight = motorcycleWeight / motorcycleCount
print("Average weight for cars: \(averageCarWeight), average weight for motorcycle: \(averageMotorcycleWeight)")
```

I'm not sure it can be done in a simpler way, but I wanted to check with you guys to see if there is :-) Thank you for your time!

**Edit**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can actually use higher order functions to achieve what you need.

```
let allVehicles = "Peugeot#950#yellow#car--Yamaha#180#black#motorcycle--Kawazasaki#210#green#motorcycle"

let vehichlesArray = allVehicles.componentsSeparatedByString("--")
let vehicles = vehichlesArray.map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString("#") }

let cars = vehicles.filter { $0[3] == "car" }
let motorcycles = vehicles.filter { $0[3] == "motorcycle" }

let carsCount = cars.count
let motorcyclesCount = motorcycles.count

let carWgt = cars.reduce(0, combine: { $0 + (Int($1[1]) ?? 0) })
let motorcycleWgt = motorcycles.reduce(0, combine: { $0 + (Int($1[1]) ?? 0) })
```

However, I believe that object-oriented architecture will better suit this kind of scenario.

Comment: Hi @koropok! Thank you so much for your answer. I do however get some errors and I added them in my post. How would you make it object oriented?

Comment: hello, the errors are because you have redeclaration of variable carWeight and motorcycleWeight. I've edited my answer. As for object-oriented programming its not something which I can explain in such a short time. Its along the idea of encapsulating your car and motorcycle into objects where their weight, color, etc are store as variable within the object. You can learn much more about object oriented programming by googling it, they are available free almost everywhere! One good place to start is https://www.raywenderlich.com/81952/intro-object-oriented-design-swift-part-1

Comment: Worked like a charm and it is much simpler! Will look into object oriented programming, thanks for your help :-)